# Does APNS-SHARP is the library that send multiple payloads in one connection?

Tags: c#, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I'm new for iPhone application development. I'm use APNS-SHARP for Push Notification.
I want to know that this library use the method that "send multiple payloads in one connection". Can I use this library for bulk payload?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

APNS-SHARP has two types of sending (`NotificationServiceDistributionType`):

**Sequential** :
                 Loops through all connections in sequential order to ensure completely even distribution
**Random**
Randomly chooses a connection to use